# Cell significant digits of floating point numbers - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I change the cell (table_data) significant digits of floating point numbers (e.g., 2 numbers after the digit?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
format short e
 
table_data =vertcat(num2cell(rand(25)),num2cell(rand(25)));
```

Comment: I have to downvote this question because something here is wrong. You accepted an answer that converts your cell array of numbers to a cell array of char arrays.

Comment: I did not downvote you. I have no problem if the result is stored as char and I do not see that the result is not correct.

Comment: But Stackoverflow is Q&A platform with the goal to help future users and your question is how to change the significant digits of a floating point number and not how to convert a floating point number to a char array. My downvotes don't depend of you downvoting me. They only depend on how helpful a question or answer will be for other users in the future. If you ask a question and mark an answer that doesn't answer your question it's a bad question.

Comment: Additionally I would downvote this question because it doesn't show any effort or research: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
table_data=cellfun(@(x) sprintf('%0.2f', x), vertcat(num2cell(rand(25)),num2cell(rand(25))), 'UniformOutput',0);
```

If you want to change the number of digit (e.g. 4, change to `'%0.4f'`).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is multiply with 100, round/floor/ceil/fix and divide by 100.

```
table_data = vertcat(num2cell(round(rand(25) * 100) / 100), num2cell(round(rand(25) * 100) / 100));
```

Of course you can first create the cell array and change it later:

```
table_data = cellfun(@(x) round(x * 100) / 100, vertcat(num2cell(rand(25)), num2cell(rand(25))), 'UniformOutput',0);
```